# Is there a way to send multiple actions from a pipe in redux observable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Now all I wanted to do was before myAPI.postUserData(action.payload); I wanted to call PROFILE_FETCHING_DATA_LOADING for ActivityIndicator to appear but I am not able to do it.

```
const profileFetchingDataEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(PROFILE_FETCHING_DATA_ATTEMPT),
    flatMap((action) => {
      myAPI.postUserData(action.payload);
      return [action];
    }),
    map((action) => {
      console.log("EPIC profileFetchingDataEpic", action);
      return {
        type: PROFILE_FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS,
        payload: action.payload,
      };
    })
  );
```

Any ideas guys

Comment: Just wondering, why are you returning the same action (PROFILE_FETCHING_DATA_ATTEMPT)  that you have dispatched(PROFILE_FETCHING_DATA_ATTEMPT) within the flatmap?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand you correctly. If you want multiple emits created by one observable emit you can:

1. map your multiple values to an array
2. mergeAll them to single emits

```js
const { Observable } = rxjs;
const { mapTo, mergeAll } = rxjs.operators;

const source$ = new Observable(sub => sub.next(void 0)).pipe(
  mapTo(['one', 'two']),
  mergeAll()
)

source$.subscribe(v => console.log('source$', v))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

The `mapTo` represents your `map((action) => ...`. Here you need to create all the actions that you want to emit after a specific action is incoming.